# Mapping a list of nested yaml to a list of objects in Spring boot Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am using the spring cloud config server/client to get some centralized yaml config represented asshown below:

```
app:
      workflows:
        - name: name1
          tag : tag1 
          producer:
              acks: all
              retries: 0
          consumer: 
              id: 1
              timeout: 1
        - name: name2
          tag : tag2 
          producer:
              acks: xyz
              retries: 1
          consumer: 
              id: 2
              timeout: 3
```

I have an issue getting the nested producer and consumer elements, sofar they are showing up as null within the Config objects. This is what currently was able to have:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="app")
public class MSConfiguration {

    private List<Config> workflows = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<Config> getWorkflows() {
        return workflows;
    }



    public static class Config {
        private String name;
        private String tag;
        private Producer producer;
        private Consumer consumer;

        //getters and setters here

    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="producer")
    public static class Producer {
        private String acks;
        private String retries;

        //getters and setters here

    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="consumer")
    public static class Consumer {
        private String id;
        private String timeout;

        //getters and setters here
    }
```

Comment: Not able to replicate your issue at all, your property file populates the object graph in my machine without any issues. Note that you don't require `@ConfigurationProperties` on `Consumer` and `Producer`. Are you perhaps using an older version of Spring Boot?

Comment: are you sure you are not having TAB characters in your YAML file? This is typical for a file where it looks like `id` is indented further than `consumer` but where it is not due to some TAB character.

Comment: Not sure what was wrong. I re-run the same code and now producer/consumer are populated. Thanks for your reply.